# Azure Spatial Anchors HoloLens Sample Project Fails

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to run the Azure Spatial Anchors sample project from [Quickstart: Create a HoloLens app with Azure Spatial Anchors, in C++/WinRT and DirectX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-hololens).

It builds but at runtime I receive a null pointer exception on the first Update. The call stack looks like this:

```
SampleHoloLens.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Perception_Spatial_ISpatialLocatorAttachedFrameOfReference<winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::ISpatialLocatorAttachedFrameOfReference>::GetStationaryCoordinateSystemAtTimestamp(const winrt::Windows::Perception::PerceptionTimestamp & timestamp) Line 500  C++
SampleHoloLens.exe!SampleHoloLens::SampleHoloLensMain::Update() Line 186    C++
SampleHoloLens.exe!SampleHoloLens::AppView::Run() Line 95   C++
SampleHoloLens.exe!winrt::impl::produce<SampleHoloLens::AppView,winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView>::Run() Line 920 C++
```

This happens in both Release and Debug. I'm building and running in Release, x86 to the Local Machine as described in the readme. I am currently using an an HL1.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the same call stack you describe for that deployment configuration, but it looks like you're running into this because you're setting the deployment target to "Local Machine" instead of "Device" in Visual Studio.

For deploying to a HL1, the quickstart guide recommends to:

> change the Solution Configuration to Release, change Solution Platform
>   to x86, and select Device from the deployment target options.

Can you please try with the correct deployment target and report back?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the deployment target to "device" solved this issue.